# Is there any way to stream data from UI to a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, stream

Can we stream data from UI(javascript) to servlet?

basically, I want to stream data string which looks like below :

street,city,zip,state,beds,baths,sq__ft,type,sale_date,price,latitude,longitude
3526 HIGH ST,SACRAMENTO,95838,CA,2,1,836,Residential,Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,59222,38.631913,-121.434879
51 OMAHA CT,SACRAMENTO,95823,CA,3,1,1167,Residential,Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008,68212,38.478902,-121.431028
....
....

And in my servlet or JSP, I will download this data as a CSV file, like below :

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName); 
PrintWriter outx = response.getWriter();
outx.println(request.getParameter("data"));
outx.flush();
outx.close();
```

(**Why I am sending the data from UI to servlet is a project specific decision, and I don't want to go there unless it's absolutely necessary.)

But, since the data that I want to send from UI to Server, might be very large in size, so I want to stream it to the servlet, instead of sending the whole string at once, to avoid any memory issue. And later would download the data from the servlet to the client's machine, as shown above.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea on how to do it. Would really appreciate if the answers are only specific to streaming data from ui to server.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: or if keeping of the state is not important just use ajax

Comment: @Andreas.. I tried using WebSocket, but I was not sure on how to get the httpservlet response object inside onMessage method of the Socket class :

Comment: @Andreas.. 
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
        try {
         session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I want to use that response to set the header, and download the data as csv :
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);

Comment: Sorry, I apparently misunderstood what you meant by *streaming* (continuous sending without need for response). If you want response for each packet, then @ScaryWombat is correct, and AJAX would likely be what you want.

Comment: @Andreas.. actually you were right, I want to send a continuous stream, and when I receive all the packets in the Socket(which I guess Socket would take care of automatically), I want to generate a CSV from the combined packets.